# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Inline Powershell script failing to run python unittest suite

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines, python-unittest

I have a release pipeline setup in Azure DevOps to run a regression test suite.  I am running these tests remotely on a <strike>Microsoft</strike> self-hosted Windows Agent using Selenium (Python bindings) and the Python unittest framework, which invokes chromedriver.exe to run tests.

When the release job reaches the task Run Python Unit Tests however, it freezes and I don't see any output (although, when I open the task manager on the agent
I can see chromedriver and chome instances running which suggests that something is happening).

Other info -

- I am able to connect to the agent sucessfully as all my repos and latest commits are pulled down (from an earlier task in the pipeline)
- the Chromedriver path is set as an environment variable on the agent
- I am using Chromedriver 2.43
- I am using Python 2.7.14 as the interpreter (also set as an env variable in the Path)

The inline powershell task has the following in the Script to run field -

**cd C:\path\to\folder\with\tests**

**python tests.py staging**

The message displayed when this task runs in DevOps pipeline is -

*Waiting for console output from an agent...*

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zolXS.png)

When I run the tests locally on the agent with the exact same command (opening the cmd.exe terminal on the agent), I can see chromedriver opening and the tests running as expected (with output in the terminal too)

Why am I unable to <strike>run</strike> see these tests running when invoked from the inline powershell task in the release pipeline but able to see the tests run when invoked on the VM?  And why does the output still not show as the tests are running?

(I have also tried a normal cmd.exe task in place of the inline powershell task, the same issue was encountered)

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you :)

**EDIT:**

Ran a simple selenium test to check everything was working and got a successful result. However -

- I was still unable to see console output as the test was executing
- I was still unable to "see" anything executing on the VM (so it appeared to be running as a background task but could not see chrome launching and navigating to pages etc)

Comment: i'd start by validating a simplest possible single selenium test works (actually I'd start with verifying software you need for tests exists on the hosted agent, which it might not)

Comment: Did you try just waiting few minutes and then refresh? sometimes it's take time to get the output form the console and you will see `Waiting for console output from an agent` but the task working.

Comment: I've tried waiting many minutes and refreshing (hours even :D) Everything I need for running the tests exists (all python packages), as I'm able to run the tests when I remote into the agent and launch them from the terminal there.  I'll try kicking off a simple selenium test remotely from the Azure DevOps pipeline

Comment: If you are able to remote to the server with the agent, is it really a [Microsoft-Hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts&tabs=yaml)?

Comment: @Matt yes, you're right - there's a mixture of both self and microsoft hosted agents, it gets confusing!  Edited for clarity :)